# Concatenate dependent on values in the row above

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I have an excel chart with a bunch of data

Every few rows is blank

When there is a blank row I would like to concatenate the cells in column A and last 4 characters of column B from the row below, as long as the cell in column A below does not equal "."

I have the following:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    For Each cell In Columns("A")
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[1]C<>""."",CONCATENATE(R[1]C,RIGHT(R[1]C[1],4)),"""")"
    Range("A2").Select

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why entire Col A?
2. If you are using the `cell` object to loop then why use `ActiveCell`?

My recommendation is to find the last row in Col A and then take that into account in identifying your actual range and then loop through that.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last row in col A which has data
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Check each cell in the relevant range
        For Each aCell In .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            If aCell.Value = "" Then _
            aCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C<>""."",CONCATENATE(R[1]C,RIGHT(R[1]C[1],4)),"""")"
        Next aCell
    End With
End Sub
```